# How to check whether all elements in an array are null or not

Tags: iphone

I have a code in which i want to do some thing when all elements in an array are null. Please help me in doing this.

Comment: My array is of type NSMutableArray. When i log the values in the array it shows (
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>"
)

Comment: can u show your initialization of NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple. You have to check your array by using this line

```
int count = 0;

for (int i=0; i<array.count; i++)
{
    NSString *str = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    if (str == (id)[NSNull null] && str.length == 0 && [str isEqualToString:@"<null>"])
    {
        count++;
        if (count == array.count)
        {
            // here you get all object are null
        }
    }
}
```

Good Luck !!!

Comment: My array is of type NSMutableArray. When i log the values in the array it shows (
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>"
)

Comment: OK, You can check your all object in for loop for <null>. I have updated my answer. PLease check and revert me if any issue.

Comment: Don't forget to accept is as answer. Please do it

Comment: @Niks, You have to click on checkmark if it has resolved your problem.

Comment: i have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

NSArray and other collections can't take nil as a value, since nil is the "sentinel value" for when the collection ends. You can find if an object is null by using:

```
if (myObject == [NSNull null]) 
{
    // do something because the object is null
}
```

Or

If you want to check if it is empty:

```
if ([myMutableArray count] == 0) { ... }

If you want to check if the variable is nil:

if (!myMutableArray) { ... }

or:

if (myMutableArray == nil) { ... }
```

Comment: My array is of type NSMutableArray. When i log the values in the array it shows (
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>"
)

Comment: Show your Nsmutable Array code here how you initilize.

Answer (score 0):

If the 'array' in question is an NSArray or subtype, then you have nothing to do because the collection forbids `nil` elements.

Otherwise, maybe you are interested in enumerating the values against the `NSNull` instance:

```
bool Foo(NSArray * pArray) {
 assert(pArray.count);
 id nul = NSNull.null;
 for (id at in pArray) {
  if (at != nul)
   return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

Comment: My array is of type NSMutableArray. When i log the values in the array it shows (
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>"
)

Comment: @Niks most likely `NSNull`, though they could be strings or they could be a number of other types. you need to determine what they are - the debug description won't be of use (beyond debug logging).

Comment: i just want to check whether all values in an array are null.

Comment: @Niks i've tried to explain that if it is an NSArray they are not null, that it is not possible. it will have to be some kind of instance of some kind of object whose `-description` returns `"<null>". that is, a "surrogate null" such as `NSNull`. hope that helps you see why it is not as simple as it would seem.

Answer (score 0):

if (!yourarray || !yourarray.count){

}

If statement to check if array is not null and if not checks if it is empty... Then whatever you like...

Answer (score 0):

use this function

```
-(BOOL)checkArrayHavingNullEntry:(NSMutableArray *)array
{
  for (id obj in array) {
  if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
   return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```